# Not using AsNoTracking will Lock the table?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Is fetching data from EF will keep it locked till SaveChanges executed? I just want to read the data without changing it.

A lot of users are accessing the same table and applying changes on it (Hundreds of users).

I read set of posts regarding to concurrency, SNAPSHOT transitions, etc.. But I just want to know if reading the data then executing long logic after that, are they kept locked till request finished.

```
var lst = db.Emps.Where(e=> e.FirstName == "John" && e.Kids.Any(k=>k.FirstName == "Tim").ToList();
.
.
.
```

Is adding AsNoTracking will make any difference (Regarding to LOCKING issue)?

```
var lst = db.Emps.AsNoTracking().Where(e=> e.FirstName == "John" && e.Kids.Any(k=>k.FirstName == "Tim").ToList();
.
.
.
```

Comment: read this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, `AsNoTracking` only disables automatic detection of changes you perform on entities. That's all. You may want to use `Transactions`

```
public static void WithTransaction(DbContext ctx, Action fn) {
    ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    {
        fn();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    ctx.Database.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: It will also avoid getting OptimisticConcurrencyException thrown ?